# Gitlab apt repository is extremely slow

Tags: git, repository, gitlab, apt, aptitude

The automatic [Gitlab installer (Omnibus package)](https://about.gitlab.com/downloads/) did setup an automatic repository on my Debian Jessie's apt. While this is very easy to use, it's extremely slow! Running the apt update command

```
sudo apt-get update
```

is extremely fast with all other repos sources (takes 2-5 seconds), but with gitlab it takes 20-30 seconds.

Am I the only one facing this issue?

Is there a way to use a faster mirror for gitlab?

Answer (score 2):

I had problems installing GitLab. `apt-get` doesn't make any progress it always seemed to be hanging.

At the end I found this GitLab issue: [Apt-get install hangs on Ubuntu 14.04](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/1722)

Someone encourages the use of `apt-fast` instead of `apt-get`. I followed his advice and installed `apt-fast`. Then I was able to install GitLab finally.

Comment: Thanks. I'll consider this as a backup plan if I don't find a solution :-)